# How to compare two tables from different databases

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, algorithm, comparable

I have two databases, SqlServer 2016 & Oracle 10 (mirror replication).

I want to compare two the same tables from different databases without getting all  data from tables on client.

**E.g.:** I have two huge tables (size > 500 MB) how can I do it ?
Maybe anywhere has some algorithms which do it ...

P.S. I have implemented some algorithm but speed of works this algorithm too slowly and work accuracy very low.

Comment: Are you able to setup DBlink? Can you export/import table from one server to another? What is yopur data? You can compare some keys only or you need compare all fields? Your question is very general. Please provide more details.

Comment: No, I cannot import/export from one to another manually (replication process is auto) and I cannot block tables on long time.
I need check two tables in some time by clicking on button in my app. My data is datatime, varchar, timestamp, numberic, etc. columns. I need compare all fields, whole table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OPENROWSET to connect to Oracle from SQL Server

```
select * from
OPENROWSET('OraOLEDB.Oracle','<tnsname>';'someuser';'somepassword', 
'SELECT * FROM schema.table_to_compare') A 
FULL JOIN sqlserver.table_to_compate B
ON A.field = B.field
```

Comment: Thank you - but this case doesn't suit (due to different server locations, traffic, network collisions, etc.). I wish to know result of comparison on my client (WPF application), I admit getting some size of comparison results on my client.

Comment: Maybe has some variants to get result (some hash, checksum algorithms) datasets from two databases and make final comparison on my client ?